How much time had passed from the start of the story until the end?
In Spirited Away

 it seems that time moved very fast in the spirit world and out of the spirit world.
 It is only moments from when Chihiro left the restaurant and walked on the bridge that it became nightfall. You can see the shadows moving quickly across the bridge.
 Then at the end of the story when they exit, the building and passage way they entered has thick vegetation and decaying paint. There is also dust and leaves on the car.

How much time has passed? How long was Chihiro in that world? What there any significance to this?
Note:
We could probably do the math on the spirit world time because we have two variables. We have Chihiro and Haku having a conversation and we have the shadow moving across the bridge at the same time. We that we might be able to determine how fast the sun moves.

I left my car in a car park a few weeks ago. When I returned a few hours later, it was covered covered in dust, leaves and a not inconsiderable amount of bird poo.

I always thought that a few days had passed (matching Chihiro’s experiences), and that the condition of the car was to emphasize that point. But again, it isn’t necessarily clear that “spirit time” and “human time” are the same. So without an answer from Miyazaki or someone else who worked on the film we have only opinions.

–1 for gratuitous use of spoiler markdown.

@Lexible Aren't we supposed to put story spoilers behind spoiler flag?
